# Module not found: Can't resolve when creating a module

Tags: javascript, express, npm

I'm making a module however im getting this error, when i import it in my test application.

> ../fetchModule/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve './Myfetch' in
>   '/Users/******/nodework/fetchModule'

here is the folder structure

[image]

and here is the package.json

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "fetchmodule",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a fetch module for our project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file index.js"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.0"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Myfetch from  './Myfetch';

export default class Fetch extends Component {
 .......

}
```

**MyFetch**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class MyFetch extends Component {
  .....
}
```

Comment: can you show your import statement from index.js

Comment: yes will update in a sec.

Comment: ok its updated.

Comment: ok so you're using react, can you also post the MyFetch file? I want to see how you're exporting that file

Comment: got it ill show in one sec.

Comment: i think i found out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the folder structure, its the path. You should import it in index.js as

```
import MyFetch from './src/Myfetch'
```

Comment: let me give this a shot.

Comment: thanks this solve the problem, but idk why though. Why do i need to refer to `src` ?

Comment: You are importing it in index.js so that's your current working directory. For your local modules you have to specify the path relative to your current js file.